# Prove that a function from a metric space into [0,1] is continuous and real valued.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

$(M,d)$ is a metric space and $X$ is a subset of $M$. define $d(x,X) = \inf \{d(x,y)| y \epsilon X\}$

A and B are closed subsets of M such that $A \cap B = \phi$

a. Prove that $$g(x) = \frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A) + d(x,B)}$$ is continuous from M into [0,1].

b. Also prove that there exists open subsets $U,V$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$ and $U \cap V = \phi$

The question had 2 previous parts where I had to prove that $f(x) = d(x,X)$ is continuous, I managed to prove that but am fumbling with these. $\\\\\\\\$

Comment: I think you mean $A\cap B=\emptyset $. You will also need $M=A\cup B$ I think.

Comment: The first part is correct. The second is not necessarily true. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose you have shown a then you can take $U =g^{-1} [0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $V =g^{-1}(\frac {1}{2},1]$

Comment: What is A and B here then?

Comment: $A=g^{-1}(0)$ and $B=g^{-1}(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity is quite clear one you know that $f(x) = d(x,A)$ is continuous, and so is $f'(x) = d(x,B)$.

Check that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies that $d(x,A) + d(x,B) > 0$.
This uses that $x \in \overline{X}$ iff $d(x,X) = 0$ for subsets of $X$.

So we have a quotient of continuous functions (you need that division and addition are continuous on the real numbers), which is continuous.

b) follows from pulling back disjoint neighbourhoods of $0$ and $1$ under this $g$.

Comment: > pulling back disjoing neighbourhoods? 
What does this mean?

Comment: See @Rise's comment above.